# Synchronous multi login test execution

Tags: selenium, cucumberjs, browserstack, nightwatch, selenium4

I would like to automate the following use-case using selenium grid (nightwatch) / browserstack,

1. Login using 1st user
2. Login with 2nd user in incognito window or different browser
3. 2nd user is a manager to 1st and interacts with user 1
4. Automate flows to test if 1st & 2nd user interactions works as expected

Is it possible to automate this flow? Parallel testing cannot be possible as the above use-case happens synchronously

Answer (score 0):

I would like to let you know that your use case would be possible if the same is possible by you locally at your end on a local Selenium grid at your end.

Note:- You cannot open 2nd browser in the same session however you can open another tab window and also can open a session in incognito. Should you be able to open a normal browser and an incognito window in the same session locally, then you would be able to test your use case on Browserstack as well.